# Using trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt with a panGestureRecognizer with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a view which I've added a UIPanGestureRecognizer to.

I've noticed that the trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt does not work together with this pan.  When I remove the pan the trailing swipe works fine.

Is there anyway to use both simultaneously?

I know when I setup the pan I can do the following:

```
// add gesture recognizer
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan))
panGesture.require(toFail: <???>)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

But because for a tableView trailing swipe I don't define the swipe myself I have no reference to it.

Is there anyway around this issue?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`.

It might work.